# Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Setting QUOTED_IDENTIFIER to 'OFF' is not supported

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse, sqlcmd

I am trying to authenticate to Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool from the terminal command line utility `sqlcmd`   ... this syntax works from a ubuntu laptop

```
sqlcmd -S foo -d bar -G    #  sudo apt-get install sqlcmd
```

however from a windows 10 box getting error

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Setting QUOTED_IDENTIFIER to 'OFF' is not supported

I would like to use Windows Authentication so if there is a better tool to let me execute SQL script files against Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL pool from a windows 10 terminal please pipe in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the SQLCMD `-I` argument to set `QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS ON`. SQLCMD explicitly turns the option off for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Just because you didn't post myValue / POWER(10, myScale) as an answer